# Why does FreeRadius fail to process the accounting response from Fortigate?

Tags: freeradius

I have configured a freeradius proxy (3.0.16) on Ubuntu (4.15.0-47-generic). It receives the radius accounting packets from another radius server running on Ubuntu and writes those to another radius server on running on Fortigate.

```
Radius Server ---> Proxy Radius Server ---> Fortigate Radius Server
```

I have configured copy-acct-to-home-server to include the Realm in proxy.conf

```
proxy.conf ( Realm definition )

home_server myFortigate {
    type = acct
    ipaddr = <IP address of Fortigate Interface Running Radius>
    port = 1813
    secret = superSecret
   }

home_server_pool myFortigatePool {
    type = fail-over
    home_server = myFortigate
}



realm myFortigateRealm {

    acct_pool = myFortigatePool
    nostrip
}
```

copy-acct-to-home-server entry

```
preacct {
            preprocess

            update control {
                            Proxy-To-Realm := myFortigateRealm
            }
            suffix

    }
```

After I run the freeradius -X, I also run tcpdump from a new session

```
tcpdump -ni eth01 port 1812 or port 1813
```

and get the following log

```
15:03:40.225570 IP RADIUS_PROXY_IP.56813 > FORTIGATE_INTERFACE_IP.1813: RADIUS, Accounting-Request (4), id: 0x31 length: 371 
15:03:40.236155 IP FORTIGATE_INTERFACE_IP.1813 > RADIUS_PROXY_IP.56813: RADIUS, Accounting-Response (5), id: 0x31 length: 27
```

Which basically shows it is sending the account request to fortigate radius server and receiving the accounting response.

But strangely freeradius -X debug output shows a request time out for the same radius server on Fortigate and it ultimately tags the server as zombie

```
Starting proxy to home server FORTIGATE_INTERFACE_IP port 1813
(14) Proxying request to home server FORTIGATE_INTERFACE_IP port 1813 timeout 30.000000
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
(14) Expecting proxy response no later than 29.667200 seconds from now
```

Waking up in 3.5 seconds.

and Finally it gives up

```
25)   accounting {
(25)     [ok] = ok
(25)   } # accounting = ok
(25) ERROR: Failed to find live home server: Cancelling proxy
(25) WARNING: No home server selected
(25) Clearing existing &reply: attributes
(25) Found Post-Proxy-Type Fail-Accounting
(25) Post-Proxy-Type sub-section not found.  Ignoring.
```

So the situation is the Radius proxy is sending accounting packets to Fortigate Radius server (could be seen in both freeradius and fortigate logs)
tcpdump shows that Radius proxy is receiving accounting response from the fortigate, but for some reason freeradius process doesn't recognize (or can not read) accounting response. It may be some interoperability issue or I have missed to set some flag. Requesting help from the experts to isolate and rectify the issue.

Comment: run strace and verify the kernel is providing the packet to FreeRADIUS (i.e. FreeRADIUS reads the packet from a socket), if it's not, it's usually because of RPF (https://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering)

Comment: Hi @ArranCudbard-Bell

I have enabled strace and can see that radius proxy is able to receive the response packet from fortigate radius server and mark it as live. Then suddenly it stops receiving the response (although the response sent could be seen in fortigate log and tcpdump) and marks it as zombie. I have included the log snippets in the question.